# VB.NET get control name from button created at run time

Tags: vb.net

I have this code to create 3 buttons at run time, which seems to be working ok.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim rawData As String
        Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\temp\test.txt"
        Dim data() As String

        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)

        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            rawData = objReader.ReadLine() ' & vbNewLine
            data = Split(rawData, ",")
            'data 0 = X loc, data 1 = Y loc, data 2 = Part Num, data 3 = Reference Des

            Dim dynamicButton As New Button
            dynamicButton.Location = New Point(data(0), data(1))
            dynamicButton.Height = 20
            dynamicButton.Width = 20
            dynamicButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
            dynamicButton.BackColor = Color.Transparent
            dynamicButton.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(10, Color.Transparent)
            'dynamicButton.Text = "+"
            dynamicButton.Name = data(2)
            dynamicButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.White
            'dynamicButton.Font = New Font("Georgia", 6)
            AddHandler dynamicButton.Click, AddressOf DynamicButton_Click
            Controls.Add(dynamicButton)
            Dim myToolTipText = data(3)
            ToolTip1.SetToolTip(dynamicButton, myToolTipText)
        Loop

    End Sub
```

I want to get the control name that was created when I click a button, but I cannot seem to get what I need. I have been doing this on the dynamicButton_click event.

```
 Private Sub DynamicButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        For Each cntrl In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf cntrl Is Button Then

                MsgBox("")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You attached an event handler to the dynamic button and that is hitting?

Couple ways you can do this:

This will give you the button you just clicked without needing to loop, the sender is the button.  You need to cast it from the object to button:

```
MessageBox.Show(DirectCast(sender, Button).Name)
```

Otherwise, inside your loop, cast cntrl (the generic `Control` object) to the specific `Button` control object and then get the name.

```
Dim btn as Button = DirectCast(cntrl, Button)
MessageBox.Show(btn.Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is cast the `sender` variable to button.  It will tell you which control was the source of the event:

```
Private Sub DynamicButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked: " & btn.Name)
End Sub
```

Comment: No problem.  If you need to quickly access those specific dynamic buttons at a later time, you could always create a `List(Of Button)` at Form level and add your buttons to that as well when you create them.  This would be better than trying to iterate over the whole Controls() collection looking for them...which wouldn't even work if the buttons were added to a container other than the Form itself.  In that case, you'd need to search that container, or possibly do a recursive search.

Comment: Thanks for your time Idle_Mind, that sounds like something I will want to explore later. I am in the very early stage of what I want to do with this, so I want to consider all possible solutions for efficiency. I could end up possibly creating 500 or more buttons at run time.

Comment: 500 or more buttons?  You probably need a DataGridView then.

Comment: I will have to look into that. I have never used the DataGrid before.